# Binding datacontext viewmodel to usercontrol view when using Mvvm

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I need some help binding the viewModel to the two usercontrol views I have created.

Have created a Reservation Window that should contain these two usercontrols.

**What i got:**

- ReservationView (Window)
- ReservationListView (Usercontrol)
- ReservationDetailView (Usercontrol)

**ReservationView (Window) class**

```
public partial class ReservationView : Window
{
    public ReservationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //DataContext = null;              
    }
}
```

**ReservationListView (Usercontrol) class:**

```
public partial class ReservationListView : UserControl, IViewReservationListViewModel
{
    public ReservationListView(IViewReservationListViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

The IViewReservationListViewModel is just a empty interface which makes the contact between the usercontrol view and the viewModel.

**ReservationListViewModel**

```
public class ReservationListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IViewReservationListViewModel
{
    public ReservationListViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to set the local:"usercontrol" in the xaml inside ReservationView, I get the following error:

```
The type "ReservationListView" does not include any accessible constructors.
```

How should I link those two usercontrol to the respective viewModels when I use MVVM?

Comment: To create it as you're trying to, ReservationListView needs a public constructor with no parameters. You'll have to give it the viewmodel by binding. Conventionally, if a viewmodel owns a list (e.g. `ReservationList`) of something, its view would create a control to display that list, and bind the child control's properties to appropriate parts of the viewmodel. If the view and the control both use the same type/instance of VM, you'd bind `<ReservationListView DataContext="{Binding}" .../> -- that binds the parent's datacontext to that property.

Comment: The `DataContext` property is usually inherited from the parent UI object, and should almost never be set in code-behind like you have in your UserControl. So get rid of that line, make it a parameterless constructor, and make sure your DataContext is inherited or set from the parent UI object properly. [Clemens's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36778349/302677) is one example of how to do that. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would usually have a MainViewModel like

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ReservationListViewModel ReservationListViewModel { get; set; }
    public ReservationDetailViewModel ReservationDetailViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

and would use it in your XAML like

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<local:ReservationListView DataContext="{Binding ReservationListViewModel}"/> 
<local:ReservationDetailView DataContext="{Binding ReservationDetailViewModel}"/>
```

Your UserControls wouldn't need any constructors with parameters.

Comment: <ReservationListView DataContext="{Binding ReservationListViewModel}"/>  these lines gives me an "ReservationListView is not supported in Windows Presentation Foundation (Wpf).

Comment: I forgot the XAML namespace prefix. Added now.

Comment: And this is following the Mvvm rules?

Comment: Sure, what makes you think it wouldn't?

Comment: Okay, its working now :) I was just a little unsecure of it violated the MVVM rules.